# programmatically storing Word documents in Access as OLE Objects

Tags: vba, ms-access, ole

I need to store Word documents in an Access database as OLE Objects and then display them on a Form. To do it "properly" (as Access itself would do it) one has to add an OLE header and footer to the original file data.

I want to ask whether the algorithm for doing that is clearly known. So far I have found only that not only header and footer is added but also original Word document data is slightly modified.

Comment: Are you sure you need to do that? Makes any DB hard to manage and management isn't Access' strongest suit. Should be just a matter of dumping the doc in the db and pulling it out again.

Comment: unfortunately, yes. it's not my decision though. if it were up to me i would use similar approach as you have suggested.

Comment: Since posting your question have you been able to find any information on this from other sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is fair to say that no, the implementation details for creating OLE imbedded objects is not "clearly known", at least by the vast majority of Windows developers. The complete lack of answers to this question (until now) serves as evidence of that. Creating and deciphering OLE imbedded objects is an arcane ritual involving other applications (such as Microsoft Word) acting as OLE servers, callback functions, secret incantations, and the occasional animal sacrifice.

Pursuing this course of action would require a significant effort in order to put yourself in a position that almost everyone else is trying to escape. The vast majority of questions related to this topic are from people trying to "liberate" their OLE imbedded objects, not make more of them.

You say that "it's not your decision", so perhaps you should forward a copy of this question and its responses to the "decision maker(s)" and see if they might reconsider.